# How can I call a macro which contains a loop but only run one iteration of that loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, iteration

The macro I'm calling is in another spreadsheet that doesn't belong to me so I'd prefer not to edit their code.

Something along the lines of:

```
Sub X()
    Call MacroX
End Sub

Sub MacroX()
    For i = 1 to 100
        ... code...
    Next i
End Sub
```

But I only want `i` to be equal to `1` and not loop through the other 99 iterations.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Add both macro-codes in your question,

Comment: Unless this macro specifically includes an Escape clause you can trigger/invoke, you will not be able to do this without modifying the code.

Comment: If you can't change it at all then there's nothing to be done. Talk to the person who "owns" the code and request it to take a parameter for the `To` section so that people can tell it `to 1` or `to 100` or whatever they need. Or copy and paste the macro to your own sheet and make the alterations you need there so that you don't change the original.

Answer (score 0):

You a looking for something like that?

```
Option Explicit

Public FromMacro As Boolean 

Sub X()

    FromMacro = True

    Call MacroX

End Sub

Sub MacroX()

    Dim Iteration As Long
    Dim i As Long

    If FromMacro = True Then
        Iteration = 1
    Else
        Iteration = 100
    End If

    For i = 1 To Iteration
        MsgBox Iteration
    Next i

    FromMacro = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I think a Boolean needs to be used, but I can't add the 'FromMacro' bit of code in MacroX as it doesn't belong to me.